# Mongoengine Dynamic Document, How to add item dynamically to referencefield?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Is there a way to add new item(document) in Dynamic Document with referencefield?

I tried following way but it did not work. How could i achieve what i tried below?

```
class Product(Document):
    name = StringField()
    price = FloatField()


Class Order(DynamicDocument):
    name = StringField()


product = Product(name='phone',price=100).save()
order = Order(name='customer x')
order.product1 = ReferenceField(product)
order.save()
```